# Why is loading dll on my machine consistently failing

Tags: c#, c, dll

I am trying to learn how to call `c` `dll` method from `c#` application. I am running both c and c# as 64 bit versions.
I am following this Microsoft article [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern) - Example 2.

When I run `cm.exe` (see below) - I am getting an error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

In short, c dll consists of just this peace of code:

```
// cmdll.c
// Compile with: -LD ("cl -LD cmdll.c")
int __declspec(dllexport) SampleMethod(int i)
{
  return i*10;
}
```

C# executable is collocated with c dll and looks like this:

```
// cm.cs (compile with "csc cm.cs")
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class MainClass
{
    [DllImport("Cmdll.dll")]
      public static extern int SampleMethod(int x);

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SampleMethod() returns {0}.", SampleMethod(5));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What is going on?

> Update:
> I have managed to run cm app as 64 bit (from within Visual Studio 2022) now but I am getting this time `System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'Cmdll.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BadImageFormatException error when using C++ .dll function for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041979/badimageformatexception-error-when-using-c-dll-function-for-c)

Comment: In other words you need to make sure both the executable and the dll target the same platform, for example they should both target x86 or x64, so that the exe can load the dll.

Comment: I got rid of `BadImage...` exception thank you - now i am getting `System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'Cmdll.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'`

Comment: Please edit the question or create a new one and describe what you are doing different now. Your changes may cause the dll to be placed into a different folder where your exe cannot find it.

Comment: If you use a different operating system than Windows, case spelling of the file names may play a role (Cmddll vs cmddll)

Comment: @NineBerry You were right, running it from within VS 2022 changed the location. I am not getting 'Unable to load DLL 'Cmdll.dll' but getting yet another exception. Should I raise another issue or continue in this thread? The exception this time is: `Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' : 'A call to PInvoke function 'ConsoleApplication!MainClass::SampleMethod' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. .'
`

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602645/why-do-i-get-pinvokestackimbalance-was-detected-for-this-simple-example

Comment: Another reason might be that int is not the same type in C as in C# when compiled for 64 bit.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to specify `CDecl` calling convention in the `DllImport`